# "would you be surprised" vs "would you have been surprised"

Tags: conditional-constructions, perfect-constructions

Which of the following is right grammatically? And why?

> Would you **be** surprised if I had arrived yesterday without letting you know beforehand?
>
> Would you **have been** surprised if I had arrived yesterday without letting you know beforehand?

If both are right , is there differences between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boh are "grammatical" but they mean different things:

A 'would' question followed by 'be' (e.g. would you be surprised...) asks about a possible future situation: would you be surprised (if you learned, having previously been unaware) [that] I had arrived yesterday without letting you know beforehand?

A 'would' question followed by 'have been' (e.g. would you have been surprised...) asks about an unreal past situation (one that didn't happen): would you have been surprised (at the time) if I had arrived yesterday without letting you know beforehand?